# How does one say: adding a record previously omitted

Tags: word-choice

Let's say, in accounting, a previous spreadsheet that I passed onto my client had a missing record, but in the newest version, I have now included this missing record. How do I phrase this succinctly, perhaps even with one word?

"A revision to the previous version" would suggest a false record was made rather than the omission of a record.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're talking about a revision of a spreadsheet then I would include the addition of missing records as being in scope for "a revision".

Comment: The new spreadsheet is the "revised version" (generally neutral but with a slight nuance of an error or omission) - **amended** (indicates a past omission or error) or **updated** (generally neutral term) also work.

Comment: What about 'modified to the extent that.....' so that it is easier to track which part has been modified...?

Comment: As the posting guidelines say, this question would benefit from a sentence (or similar context) with a blank you intend to fill, what you want paraphrased, or at least a clearer explanation of exactly what you want. For instance: "Enclosed is the _ spreadsheet" or "I have _ the spreadsheet for you" or "I am performing a process of _ the spreadsheet". There are many ways of explaining the situation, but people don't normally explain things just by writing one word. You can see this in the widely differing answers.

Comment: I find "revision", "amended" and "updated" to be not conveying the fact that the amendment was due to omission of info.
"modified to the extent that" is more informative though not very succinct.
Nonetheless, very grateful for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might say that I have **rectified an omission**.

As an example from [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/rectify), we have

> We have rectified this common omission.

"rectify" often goes with "omission".

Comment: I find this to be most apt sentence. Thank you

Comment: No problem, glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

A very succint way to notify an error, in particular when there are several of them, is to write down an errata section (singular: erratum) or an ADDENDA (singular: addendum) at the end or at the beginning of the document.

ERRATA (from preceding edition)

XXX p. yyy  is now WWW
UUU p. VVV is now PPP

Comment: I was looking for a word or sentence. However, still great to learn of this method of recording amendments. Thank you, LPH